How to log a library's WebClient request and response?
I am aware of how to configure the logging if I am building the Spring Boot Webclient on my own in my code. But what if I am calling some API that encapsulates the http calls using the WebClient? Can I intercept the communication to log the request + response?

Do you specifically need the request/response message in the log of the application which is using the library? Otherwise you could configure the library to target a reverse proxy which will forward the requests to the actual service and also do the logging of request and response.

What you usually need to consider, given an external integration, is how you expect the external endpoint to behave. Once defined its basic behaviour, that could be more or less equivalent to what the actual web server does, you can mock it, using for example Mockito.
About logging, that really depends on the implementation of your integration. Usually, it is part of a standalone component that is to be injected/wired or part of a layer in the application.
I don't expect you to be testing logging string but you probably want to test strings contained in the body of a response.
That happens by means of reactor.test.StepVerifier.
It would look like something that could resemble
Mono<List<LicenseRecord>> matchLicenses = WebClientWrapper.request();
StepVerifier.create(tournamentLicenses).expectNextMatches(list -> {
            return list.size() == 1
                && list.get(0).getType().equals(LicenseType.TOURNAMENT)
                && list.get(0).getCustomerId().equals(customerId);
        }).verifyComplete()

From the official doc, there is an example here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-webflux/src/test/java/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/WebClientIntegrationTests.java
